# What is this mach_constant_base_node

Tags: jvm

In c2 architecture specific file i see the above variable. Please share 
1. what it is?
2. Whether does it has any relation to the run time constant pool.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. An IR graph node that represents a base address of the compiled method's constants table in a machine-specific manner. This node actually does nothing on x86, since the architecture allows to reference the whole range of 32-bit or 64-bit addresses inline.
2. Generally, no. Though some constants from the constant pool (particularly, floating point) may appear in that table.

*P.S. I guess HotSpot Compiler guys are too busy to browse StackOverflow :) The better place for asking C2 implementation-specific questions is [hotspot-compiler-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-compiler-dev) list.*

Comment: Sorry. I did not get completely. The constant table comes from the class files right? . So what does it contain in the Architecture specific constant base address. And how this base address is generated.

Comment: @hareeshr The constant table contains the constants referenced from JIT-compiled code. They don't necessary come from the class file, though sometimes they do. Use `-XX:+PrintAssembly` to dump the compiled code, and you'll see the `[Constants]` section among the output. What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that PPC made some changes on this area. http://hg.openjdk.java.net/ppc-aix-port/jdk8/hotspot/rev/9a8d8eff3f61 . I am trying to understand this patch.